# Alignment problem with table and fancyhdr

Tags: tables, fancyhdr

I'm having a problem with alignment in header handled with `fancyhdr`.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,italian,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\font\sans=cmss10
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{}}
\definecolor{light-blue}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,1}
\definecolor{dark-green}{RGB}{125,180,125}
\definecolor{dark-red}{RGB}{180,125,125}
\textheight 220mm
\setlength{\headheight}{90pt} %header largo circa 26mm
\fancypagestyle{egiconheader}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
    \fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{\includegraphics[height=18mm]{logo_con_scritta.jpg}}% Header Left
    \fancyhead[C]{}

    \fancyhead[R]{              
                     \begin{tabular}{ll} 
                            &\\
                            \textbf{Company }                   &  \\ 
                            \textbf{via fgfgfg, 36} &  \\ 
                            \textbf{404040 City(Prov.)}     &  \\
                            \textbf{P.I. e C.F 5455454545} &\multirow{-5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=24mm]{certificazione.png}}\\ 
                            \end{tabular} 
                        }
\fancyfoot[L]{My document}
  \fancyfoot[R]{{Pag. \thepage~di \pageref{LastPage}}}% Footer Centred

  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{3pt}% 2pt header rule
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{dark-green}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}

    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{3pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{dark-red}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
    }
    \columnsep .7cm
    \frenchspacing
    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{egiconheader}
    ciao
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this led me to the unexpected result:
[image]

While I'd expect this:
[image]

Can any one explain me what I'm wronging and help me to eliminate the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome. It would be more comfortable for helpers to have some minimal but compilable code.

Comment: To expand on what @Johannes_B said, it looks like you tried to provide one, but the content got "corrupted" somehow. The easiest way to format a code snippet is to select it, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: If you want to align the tops, you should use \raisebox{-\height}{...} on both the image and tabular.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. @Johannes_B sorry for my error in putting the code... It's my first time on this kind of _stack_ and I don't really know syntax very well. I modify my code to make it compilable but I couldent format well inside {}. I tried with post tag but somethig goes wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the long non-MWE, but what you need is a `[b]` in `\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}` like

```
\fancyhead[R]{
                     \begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
                            &\\
                            \textbf{Company }                   &  \\
                            \textbf{via fgfgfg, 36} &  \\
                            \textbf{404040 City(Prov.)}     &  \\
                            \textbf{P.I. e C.F 5455454545} &\multirow{-5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=24mm]{certificazione.png}}\\
                            \end{tabular}
                         }
```

[image]

BTW, `24mm` is too tall.

Comment: thk u finally I foud the solution!!! The best result has been in [b] as @Harish Kumar says and using raisebox as John says in the previous post. Thank u very much!